# Can $_FILES[...]['size'] be forged?

Tags: php, security, file-upload

There's a well-known caveat about not trusting the MIME type sent via file upload in PHP (`$_FILES[...]['type']`) as this is sent by the HTTP client and could therefore be forged.

There's a similar caveat for the file name (`$_FILES[...]['name']`), which is sent by the HTTP client and could contain potentially dangerous characters.

However, I can't see how the file size (`$_FILES[...]['size']`) could be forged, as it does not seem to be part of the request payload, at least I can't see it in the dev tools in Chrome, where the payload looks like:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarytYAQ3ap4cmAB46Ek
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="picture"; filename="picture.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

Original file name and MIME type are here as expected, but no sign of a size parameter.

Still, I've just stumbled upon Symfony's `UploadedFile` implementation, that considers the file size as client-originated and therefore not trustable:

[UploadedFile::getClientSize()](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html#method_getClientSize)

> Returns the file size.
>   It is extracted from the request from which the file has been uploaded. Then is should not be considered as a safe value.

Can the file size be part of the request payload, and therefore be forged, or is it always inferred from the actual file pointed to by `$_FILES[...]['tmp_name']`, and therefore always trustable?

Comment: checking the PHP source, its the actual buffer size, so it should be "safe"

Comment: It can be forged by changing the amount of file data being send.

Comment: @Dagon Could you please give a link to the relevant source code?

Comment: @Gumbo I don't understand what you mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested by [@Dagon in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564656/can-files-size-be-forged#comment-38048426), I checked the PHP source in [rfc1867.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/af6c11c5f060870d052a2b765dc634d9e47d0f18/main/rfc1867.c).

The lines involved in defining the `[size]` attribute are:

```
[1042] wlen = write(fd, buff, blen);
       ...
[1056] total_bytes += wlen;
       ....
[1242] ZVAL_LONG(&file_size, total_bytes);
       ...
[1270] snprintf(lbuf, llen, "%s[size]", param);
       ...
[1275] register_http_post_files_variable_ex(lbuf, &file_size, ...
```

Which I translate as:

- [1042](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/af6c11c5f060870d052a2b765dc634d9e47d0f18/main/rfc1867.c#L1042) The temp file is written in `wlen` size chunks
- [1056](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/af6c11c5f060870d052a2b765dc634d9e47d0f18/main/rfc1867.c#L1056) In each iteration, `wlen` is added to `total_bytes`
- [1242](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/af6c11c5f060870d052a2b765dc634d9e47d0f18/main/rfc1867.c#L1242) `total_bytes` is assigned to the `file_size` zval
- [1270](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/af6c11c5f060870d052a2b765dc634d9e47d0f18/main/rfc1867.c#L1270) The target variable name `...[size]` is assigned to `lbuf`
- [1275](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/af6c11c5f060870d052a2b765dc634d9e47d0f18/main/rfc1867.c#L1275) `file_size` is registered under the name contained in `lbuf`, `...[size]`

So without doubt, the only variable ever assigned to `$_FILES[...]['size']` is **the actual number of bytes written to the temporary file** whose path is assigned to `$_FILES[...]['tmp_name']`.

As far as I can see, **there is no way to forge the `size` attribute**.

Answer (score 2):

See [BenMorel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24577651/1640606), the short answer is, no! the size can not be forged.

The only part not to trust is the size and image type provided by the **browser**

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
<input type="file" name="pictures" accept="image/png"/>
```

In both cases, it's possible to spoof the browser, so you must implement a backend solution to further validate the size and image type.

Also thanks to @Andy Gee in the comment section for improving this answer

> $_FILES[i]['type'] is sent by the client so should not be trusted. use mime_content_type($_FILES[i]['tmp_name']) to make sure.

Or use my shameless plug: https://github.com/samayo/bulletproof

Comment: `$_FILES[i]['type']` is sent by the client so should not be trusted. use `mime_content_type($_FILES[i]['tmp_name'])` to make sure.

Comment: @AndyGee Thanks, I added more details