# Can you trust file size given by $_FILES array in PHP?

Tags: php, security, post, filesize

Sorry if it is trivial or obvious, but I could not find the answer by googling it.

From where does the `size` value in `$_FILES['name']` array come from? Could you trust the value of it (`$_FILES['name']['size']`) or should you still check it using the `filesize()` function?

In other words, is it necessary to check actual file size by `filesize` function to notice if it is properly uploaded?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can $\_FILES\[...\]\['size'\] be forged?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564656/can-files-size-be-forged)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the file is uploaded correctly and everything is fine, you **can** use the info provided by PHP superglobal `$_FILES`. Using `filesize()` adds small overhead since OS needs to inspect the file for the size. It's up to you, but checking PHP source on how it does all this indicates clearly that it correctly calculates the file size in the HTTP multipart request. Basically, you'd be doing the same job again if you were to `filesize()` the file.

The reason you can trust this directly from superglobal variable is the fact that multipart requests supply a boundary between which the data resides. By definition, it's not possible to obtain corrupt data if the protocol for extracting the data isn't followed. In other words, it means that browser sends a "delimiter" and PHP simply finds it and starts checking the text for data between that delimiter. To do this, it accurately allocates required memory and it can immediately cache the number allocated - and that number is the file size. If anything is wrong along the way, you will get errors. Therefore, if the file uploaded correctly, the information about the size is trusted.

Answer (score 9):

PHP does seem to recalculate the size of the file after it is uploaded. Although the client does send a header specifying the `content-length` of the file, based on tests (with PHP 5.5) this header is simply ignored and, instead, the length is measured. Personally, I would always use `filesize()` to get the file size since you can be more confident about which measurement is being used, but it is ultimately up to you. Either way, `$_FILES['file_name']['size']` appears to be a safe value to use.

Comment: Are you sure? From my understanding reading the [source code responsible for parsing multipart HTTP requests](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/rfc1867.c), the resulting *size* reflects the number of bytes read from the multipart part body.

Comment: @Gumbo Interesting, from what I read, it is specified by the client while `upload_max_filesize` uses the measured count as it is being uploaded. I'll try to do some tests and get back to you.

Comment: @Gumbo Yup, you're absolutely right. PHP seems to recalculate it after it is uploaded.

Answer (score 4):

You should rather check if the client-reported `$_FILES['file_name']['size']` equals the value given by `filesize()`. A difference may indicate an error during transmission of the uploaded file.