# Can I fake uploaded image filesize?

Tags: forms, security, laravel-5, image-uploading

I'm building a simple image file upload form. Programmatically, I'm using the Laravel 5 framework. Through the Input facade (through Illuminate), I can resolve the file object, which in itself is an UploadedFile (through Symfony).

The UploadedFile's API ref page ([Symfony docs](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html#method_getClientSize)) says that

> public integer | null **getClientSize**()
>
> Returns the file size. It is extracted from the request from which the
> file has been uploaded. **It should not be considered as a safe
> value.** Return Value integer|null    The file size

- What will be these cases where the uploaded filesize is wrongly reported?
- Are there known exploits using this?
- How can the admin ensure this is detected (and hence logged as a trespass attempt)?

Answer (score 1):

That method is using the "Content-Length" header, which can easily be forged. You'll want to use the easy construct $_FILES['myfile']['size']. As an answer to another question has already stated: [Can $_FILES[...]['size'] be forged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564656/can-files-size-be-forged)

This value checks the actual size of the file, and is not modified by the provided headers.

If you'd like to check for people misbehaving, you can simply compare the content-length header to your $_FILES['myfile']['size'] value.